# Deploy Solution from test environment to development environment

Tags: sharepoint-server, solution-package

I've to deploy a .wsp package from test to development environment using power shell. The package resides in the folder: B:\Development.....

Can someone help here.

Please advise.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following steps.

- Move the wsp package on Dev server
- Open the SharePoint powershell ( Run as Admin)
- Run this command to add the solution. `Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "path of the package`
- Now run `Install-SPSolution -Identity "Idenitity of wsp" -GACDeployment` You can deploy it via Central admin as well.
- lastly enable the features if required